# Is this good approach to create new branch without merging current one using git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

kindly guide me about it please, for example, I have `master` branch. My team lead assigned a task to me for terms and conditions content. So I pulled from master and then created branch `feature/terms-and-conditions` through `git checkout -b` and then commit, pushed. Just guess for one minute that my team lead does not merged with `master`.

Now `feature/terms-and-conditions` is 1 commit ahead from `master`. So here I am confused that if I created again one new branch for another feature suppose `feature/user-list` and when I will commit and push for it then there would be two branches. Both would be 1 commit ahead from `master`. In such a case there would be any conflict?

Comment: You will get conflict only if your two branches have made edits to the same line in a file, or when a file has been deleted in one branch but edited in the other. Please check this for more details. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/05/19/managing-multiple-releases-production/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You described what is probably the best approach. Assuming the two features are not related, you should have two separate branches split from master, and work on them independently.
Splitting `feature/user-list` from `feature/terms-and-conditions` is a bad idea since you would be mixing unrelated content in the same branch, and making the reviewer's life harder. Even worse, every time you get comments on the `feature/terms-and-conditions` branch, you'd have to rebase the `feature/user-list` branch, which is just a lot of grunt work.
Waiting until `feature/terms-and-conditions` is merged before starting the work on `feature/user-list` isn't technically wrong, but it's redundantly slow, and I doubt your manager will be OK with that.

Regarding conflicts - Git was designed to handle multiple parallel branches. Once the first branch is merged, you can (will?) simply rebase the second one on top of master. If the two branches didn't touch the same files, the rebase will succeed cleanly. If they did, you'll have to manage the conflict manually, but that usually shouldn't be a big deal - if it is, it means both branches touched the same areas of the code, and it was probably a bad idea working on them in parallel in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the excellent answer provided by @Mureinik

In git branch is just a pointer to the commit, so there is no problem whatsoever to maintain as many branches as you want, they're "cheap".

Now as long as the branch is not merged, its only yours so you can push to it as many times as you want, so once the `feature/terms-and-conditions` gets merged into master (and assuming you haven't merged the `feature/user-list` branch yet, you can rebase your changes on top of master. I usually do (probably there are more "precise" commands, but it does the job for me):

```
// while being on feature/user-list branch
>> git fetch --all // to fetch the changes about the origin/master update into your local git repo
>> git status // just to make sure that you don't have any work in progress
>> git rebase origin/master
```

Now the last command will put all your local commits "on top of" the last master commit. At this point you might have conflicts if you worked on the same files, but in general it should not really happen (as was already explained project-wise you'll probably won't do two changes that modify the same files at the same time). Even if there will be a confict you can resolve it.

After that, if you've already pushed to remote branch `origin/feature/user-list` you might want to forcefully push new sha1-s of your commits (`git push -f`), if you haven't pushed anything yet, you just can keep working.